# Admin method in CakePHP to add a venue to the database

Tags: php, controller, cakephp

I have a `VenuesController` and an `EventsController`. My venues controller has an `admin_add` method that, well, allows an administrator to add a venue to the database. It looks like this:

```
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Venue->save($this->request->data)) {
            $message = 'Venue has been created.';
            $this->response->statusCode(201);
            if ($this->request->params['ext'] == 'json') {
                $this->set('id', $this->Venue->id);
                $this->set('_serialize', array('id'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash($message, 'flash', array('class' => 'success'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($this->request->params['ext'] == 'json') {
                $this->set('validationErrors', $this->Venue->validationErrors);
                $this->set('_serialize', array('validationErrors'));
                $this->response->statusCode(400);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are a lot of `if ()` statements which seem like code smells to me. But they’re there because in my CMS’s events section, you can add a venue inline via a modal, which sents the request to this function via AJAX.

So my question is: can I improve the above `VenuesController::admin_add()` method, make it more intelligent without the need for the `if ()` statements, and just generally make it more CakePHP-ier?

Comment: Sometimes you can't avoid having lots of `if` statements in your code. In your case the only thing I notice that I personally don't like is that you have sections of code inside `if` statements which would be prevented by calling `if(!$some_condition) return false;` then continuing with your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have the following lines repeating:

```
    if ($this->Venue->save($this->request->data)) {
        if ($this->Venue->save($this->request->data)) {
```

I think you may try to merge them to one and the associated logic too.

Comment: I didn’t actually know I had, that’s a bug! There should only be one `save()` call. That’s late night coding for you!

Answer (score 0):

For Aditional security i would definitely include the session or the cookie component

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Cookie');
```

and inside the function this if

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') == 'admin' || $this->Cookie->read('User.role') == 'admin') {
```

for more details you could check these

- [Sessions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)
- [Cookies](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html)
- [Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Comment: This is redundant, as I check the user role in a `beforeAction()` method in my `AppController` to keep things DRY.